# aws kubernetes inter cluster communication for shipping fluentd logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, kubernetes-ingress

We got multiple k8s clusters on AWS (using EKS) each on its own VPC but they are VPC peered properly to communication to one central cluster which has an elasticsearch service that will collect logs from all clusters. We do not use AWS elasticsearch service but rather our own inside kubernetes.

We do use an ingress controller on each cluster and they have their own internal AWS load balancer.

I'm getting fluentd pods on each node of every cluster (through a daemonset) but it needs to be able to communicate to elasticsearch on the main cluster. Within the same cluster I can ship logs fine to elasticsearch but not from other clusters as they need to be able to access the service within that cluster.

What is some way or best way to achieve that?

This has been all breaking new ground for me so I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious somewhere.

Comment: We use a very similar setup. In our case, `fluentd` on the cluster nodes connects to an internal ELB in front of ES inside the "hub" VPC. This should work fine assuming all Security Group rules are correct. What's the problem you've seen within your setup?

Comment: I got a load balancer service (tcp/9200) that creates internal ELB just like your scenario. Security group associated with the ELB allows the other VPC to come through. VPC peering has all routes and security groups to allow communication both ways. I am currently using a public aws DNS zone pointing to the internal ELB (an A alias which adds dualstack in front of ELB id) but fluentd nodes from other vpc cannot still communicate with Elasticsearch. Should I use an private DNS rather?

Comment: I do get the following logs [info]: [elasticsearch] Connection opened to Elasticsearch cluster => {:host=>"elasticsearch-host.domain.com", :port=>9200, :scheme=>"http"}
 [warn]: [elasticsearch] buffer flush took longer time than slow_flush_log_threshold: elapsed_time=20.324986792053096 slow_flush_log_threshold=20.0 plugin_id="elasticsearch"